# how to get a list of request parameters in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, parameters, request

I want to use [FromQuery] to get a list (or a map<String, String>) of all request parameters and their values.
we can use in Spring boot this solution:

```
saveForm(@RequestParam Map<String,String> allParams)
```

How can I have the same solution in ASP.NET? Can I use something like:

```
saveForm([FromQuery] Map<String,String> allParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
saveForm([FromQuery] Dictionary<String, String> allParams)
```

Comment: this works but unusual, actually we may not never use it (so it's interestingly supported out of the box by the default model binding). You should use `Request.Query` instead. BTW, if any parameter name is prefixed with `allParams.` (e.g: `allParams.x`) then only ones prefixed with that same value will be bound & put in the dictionary, all the others ***will be ignored*** and you lose all those parameters :) - So it works but we need to know about that important note. Try this query string `?x=2&y=3&allParams.z=5` - you'll see only `(z,5)` is put in the dictionary.